# why does df1= df does not copy a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames that are exactly same.[Python] 
df1=df #where in df there was no column called 'SD'
but why does when I am trying to do the following operation adding the column 'SD' to both the dataframe

```
`d={
     'Score1':[62,47,55,74,31,77,85,63,42,32,71,57],
     'Score2':[89,87,67,55,47,72,76,79,44,92,99,69],
     'Score3':[89,82,12,65,47,42,46,29,42,22,39,29]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
df=df1
df1['SD'] = df.std(axis=1)`
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Because `df` and `df1` are the same DataFrame. If you want a copy of `df1`, you need to explicitly copy it: `df = df1.copy()`

Comment: @ayhan thanks for your reply, so if I am understanding correctly, they are basically same pointer? only pointers got copied by the above operation.

Comment: Yes, they point to the same object (different names of the same object). `df1.copy()` makes and returns a new object which you can modify independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good question. The short answer is because your two DataFrames are actually only one and only pandas' object (if you are familiar with the notion of pointers in C programming, this is kind of the same story here). You can check this by using the id() method on both of your DataFrames. This method gives you a unique integer per object, this integer being kind of an identification number. 
If you want df and df1 two be two different objects, you should use the copy.copy() method.

```
import copy

df1 = copy.copy(df1)
df1['SD'] = df.std(axis=1)
```

Hope that will answer your question :)